# Как сделать кастомный scrollbar для сайта?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, прокрутка

Как реализовать кастомный scrollbar на сайте, на котором используются bootstrap и его модальные окна? Перепробовал несколько плагинов, они все работают. Но когда модальное окно всплывает, а у него есть своя прокрутка, то тут уже начинаются проблемы. То окно не закрывается, то окно не прокручивается. Одним словом, не подходят они для такой реализации.

Comment: Сниппет с минимальным примером?

Comment: Самое бессмысленное и часто вредное занятие - делать кастомные скроллбары.

Comment: А что поделаешь если дизайн требует.